# Error when using curly-curly (`{{ }}`) operator with `if` clause

Tags: r, rlang

I'm struggling to understand how to use the `{{ }}` operator to pass bare variable names in custom functions. I get an error when I use the operator in conjunction with an `if` clause.

This function works:

```r
f <- function(.data, .vars=NULL){
  require(dplyr)
  df = select(.data, {{ .vars }})
  print(head(df))
}

f(iris, c(Species, Sepal.Length))
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#>   Species Sepal.Length
#> 1  setosa          5.1
#> 2  setosa          4.9
#> 3  setosa          4.7
#> 4  setosa          4.6
#> 5  setosa          5.0
#> 6  setosa          5.4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If I try to add an `if` clause, it throws an error:

```r
f <- function(.data, .vars=NULL){
  require(dplyr)
  if(!is.null(.vars)) df = select(.data, {{ .vars }})
  else df = .data
  print(head(df))
}

f(iris, c(Species, Sepal.Length))
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> Error in f(iris, c(Species, Sepal.Length)): object 'Species' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest explanation is that when `.vars` is not `NULL`, R will interpret the value (in your example: `c(Species, Sepal.Length)`) as a vector of variables, and look for these variables in your environment. Since you don't have any variable called `Species`, it throws an error.

You can fix it like this:

```r
library(dplyr)


f <- function(.data, .vars = NULL){
  
  vars <- enquo(.vars)
  
  if(!rlang::quo_is_null(vars)) df = select(.data, !!vars)
  else df = .data
  
  print(head(df))
  
}

f(iris) 
f(iris, c(Species, Sepal.Length))
```

Note that `{{x}}` is actually a shorthand for `!!enquo(x)`.

#### Elaboration (update)

- When you don't use `if`, the only place `.vars` is being used is inside `dplyr::select(.data, {{.vars}})`. In this context, the variable names in `.vars` are interpreted as being variables in the dataframe `.data`.
- When you add the `if` statement, the `.vars` is evaluated as being variables in your environment. Since they don't exist in your environment you get an error.

This is called data-masking.
[Here](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html) is a
nice article about it.

Comment: Just to see if I got this straight: when I do not use the `if` clause it works because the `{{` operator defuses and then forces evaluation; when I use the `if` clause the `{{` operator does not defuse the value?

Comment: Let me elaborate: When you don't use `if`, the only place `.vars` is being used is inside `dplyr::select(.data, {{.vars}})`. In this context, the variable names in `.vars` are interpreted as being variables in the dataframe `.data`. 

When you add the `if` statement, the `.vars` is evaluated as being variables in your environment. Since they don't exist in your environment you get an error. 

This is called data-masking. Here is a nice article about it: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html

Hopefully I was a bit clearer now. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Understood, thank you! Probably the comment is even more useful than the answer itself, please consider to include it in the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added it to the answer now :)

Answer (score 3):

@jpiversen's answer and explanation are correct, but here's a simpler fix for your function.  Instead of looking for the default value of `NULL`, just check if `.vars` is missing:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(.data, .vars){
  if(!missing(.vars)) df = select(.data, {{ .vars }})
  else df = .data
  print(head(df))
}

f(iris, c(Species, Sepal.Length))
```

By the way, I also removed `require(dplyr)` from your function.  It's generally a bad idea to use it in a function, because of the side effect of changing the search list.  Use `requireNamespace("dplyr")` and prefix functions using `dplyr::` if you're not sure it will be available.